# generic doen't check types between two property

Tags: typescript

```
type ComponentType = (...args: any) => any;

type PlatformNotificationProps<TIcon extends ComponentType = ComponentType> = {
  component: TIcon;
  arg: Parameters<TIcon>[0];
};

const PlatformNotification = (props: PlatformNotificationProps) => {};

const Icon = (name: string) => '';

const result = PlatformNotification({
  component: Icon,
  arg: 100,
});
```

In this case or 'arg' is incorrect and should be a string, or component is incorrect and should accept number instead string.
I expecting to see error in console, but everything is ok.

How I can write types for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `PlatformNotification` as a *non*-generic function, don't expect it to check types

```
const PlatformNotification = (props: PlatformNotificationProps) => {};
//    ^?
// const PlatformNotification: (props: PlatformNotificationProps</*default*/ComponentType>) => void

const result = PlatformNotification({
  component: Icon,
// ^?
// (property) component: ComponentType
  arg: 100,
// ^?
// (property) arg: any
});
```

Just make it generic and it'll work

```
const PlatformNotification = <TIcon extends ComponentType>(props: PlatformNotificationProps<TIcon>) => {};
```

Answer (score 1):

When using generics, all types along the chain need to pass over the generic arguments.

Since you are defaulting the arguments in `PlatformNotificationProps` and then using that type without configuring it, TS will not know to associate the arguments from your function to those of the generic

Here's one way you can do it by having all elements in your chain to be configurable

```
type Fn<Args extends any[] = any[]> = (...args: Args) => any;

type PlatformNotificationProps<Args extends any[], TIcon extends Fn<Args>> = {
  component: TIcon;
  arg: Parameters<TIcon>[0];
};

const PlatformNotification = <Args extends any[] = any[], Comp extends Fn<Args> = Fn<Args> >(props: PlatformNotificationProps<Args, Comp>) => {};

const Icon = (name: string) => '';

const result = PlatformNotification({
  component: Icon,
  arg: 100,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is that you are assigning a default generic to `PlatformNotificationProps`:

```
type PlatformNotificationProps<TIcon extends ComponentType = ComponentType> = {
...
```

When you call this type without a proper generic type, typescript can only infer it to be of `ComponentType`, this is why `arg` can accept numbers, because it is actually typed as `any`:

```
const result = PlatformNotification({
  component: Icon,
  arg: 100,
// ^? (property) arg: any
});
```

The same for `component` actually:

```
const result = PlatformNotification({
  component: () => null, // no errors
  arg: 100,
});
```

In order to fix this, call `PlatformNotificationProps` with a type:

```
const PlatformNotification = (props: PlatformNotificationProps<typeof Icon>) => {};
```

And now:

```
const result = PlatformNotification({
  component: Icon,
  arg: 100, // error: type `number` is not assignable to `string`
});
```

Comment: sorry but harcode types isn't solution because we lost flexability